# Google Cloud Vision API request combining

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

Is it even possible to combine in one call (in Node) requests on an image?
Instead of calling methods separately and trying to handle outputs.

```
vision.faceDetection()
vision.documentTextDetection()
vision.safeSearchDetection()
...
```

In order to get a final JSON like here in try-out section https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to make the requests separately. However, if you consider making all the requests in one operation will be useful to you, I suggest filling a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1161261) to consider having this function within the Google Cloud Vision API functionality.